# WebLogic: WLI vs BPEL?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, bpel, weblogic-integration

folks. I would really appreciate to have your help on the following question:

In the last days I've been reading about Oracle's **WebLogic**, as I'm currently working on a project that uses it. As I've never had contact with WebLogic, I've been doing some research about the infrastructure and learning the pros/cons of using WebLogic Integration (WLI) or using  BPEL for process integration purposes.

As far as I've gone, I've learnt that BPEL stands as a "layer" over WLI, exposing services as web services for local or remote invocation. But, objectively, which are the goals of each one of them (WLI and BPEL)?

I would really like to have you helping me to clarify this question, as I would like to know when shall I only use WLI and when should I use BPEL?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used WLI but I'm familiar with BPEL ... that's why I'll just talk about what i know :) ... with BPEL you can compose your [business process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process) from others web services you can exchange with them data encapsulated in XML through SOAP protocol ... You can see a BPEL process as a workflow of others web services ... when your composition is done you can expose your business process as a regular web service by his WSDL (interface) ...
For me what I hate most in BPEL is his syntax based on XML !!!!! this can be partially compensated by a good visual editor like the free one of  [NetBeans 6.5.1](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/Downloads.html) (no longer supported in new versions)

**EDIT**

We can not compare WLI to BPEL because the first is an integration system ... while the second is a language ...
BPEL is an [orchestration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_(computers)) language, as I say before you can see it as a Work-flow of others Web services ...
If you want to have the same feature in WLI you can use [JPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPD) ... or [convert](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs92/bpel/import.html) your BPEL file to a JPD ...
Maybe the question will be more appropriate if we say :

*"What is the difference between **JPD** & **BPEL**"*

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply, wj! About WLI/BPEL, isn't WLI also described in XML format? What's the main difference between WLI and BPEL?

Comment: @XpiritO : As I say before I never used WLI but I don't thik you can compare it to BPEL ... WLI is an integration system ... while BPEL is a language ... I will edit my response to be more clear about this ;)